# Unix join on more than two files

Tags: perl, text, join, paste, cut

I have three files, each with an ID and a value.

```
sdt5z@fir-s:~/test$ ls
a.txt  b.txt  c.txt
sdt5z@fir-s:~/test$ cat a.txt 
id1 1
id2 2
id3 3
sdt5z@fir-s:~/test$ cat b.txt 
id1 4
id2 5
id3 6
sdt5z@fir-s:~/test$ cat c.txt 
id1 7
id2 8
id3 9
```

I want to create a file that looks like this...

```
id1 1 4 7
id2 2 5 8
id3 3 6 9
```

...preferably using a single command.

I'm aware of the join and paste commands. Paste will duplicate the id column each time:

```
sdt5z@fir-s:~/test$ paste a.txt b.txt c.txt 
id1 1   id1 4   id1 7
id2 2   id2 5   id2 8
id3 3   id3 6   id3 9
```

Join works well, but for only two files at a time:

```
sdt5z@fir-s:~/test$ join a.txt b.txt 
id1 1 4
id2 2 5
id3 3 6
sdt5z@fir-s:~/test$ join a.txt b.txt c.txt 
join: extra operand `c.txt'
Try `join --help' for more information.
```

I'm also aware that paste can take STDIN as one of the arguments by using "-". E.g., I can replicate the join command using:

```
sdt5z@fir-s:~/test$ cut -f2 b.txt | paste a.txt -
id1 1   4
id2 2   5
id3 3   6
```

But I'm still not sure how to modify this to accomodate three files.

Since I'm doing this inside a perl script, I know I can do something like putting this inside a foreach loop, something like join file1 file2 > tmp1, join tmp1 file3 > tmp2, etc. But this gets messy, and I would like to do this with a one-liner.

Comment: I'm also aware that this is a piece of cake with an SQL inner join, but I don't want to load all this into a database first.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`join a.txt b.txt|join - c.txt`

should be sufficient

Comment: Alternatively: `join <(join a.txt b.txt) c.txt`

Comment: This works well. join a b | join - c | join - d ...etc. That one was easier to script than the <(join) version, but also works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing it **inside a Perl script**, is there any specific reason you're NOT doing the work in Perl as opposed to spawning in shell?

Something like (NOT TESTED! caveat emptor):

```
use File::Slurp; # Slurp the files in if they aren't too big
my @files = qw(a.txt b.txt c.txt);
my %file_data = map ($_ => [ read_file($_) ] ) @files;
my @id_orders;
my %data = ();
my $first_file = 1;
foreach my $file (@files) {
    foreach my $line (@{ $file_data{$file} }) {
        my ($id, $value) = split(/\s+/, $line);
        push @id_orders, $id if $first_file;
        $data{$id} ||= [];
        push @{ $data{$id} }, $value;
    }
    $first_file = 0;
}
foreach my $id (@id_orders) {
    print "$d " . join(" ", @{ $data{$id} }) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: It's something I'd like to be able to do at the command line as well. I'm essentially using perl to glue together a handful of other programs and scripts written by other folks (python, C++, etc). a.txt, b.txt, etc are output from one of the python scripts that I now need to mash together before importing them into a stats program.

Comment: @StephenTurner - as long as you don't mind paying the (not too huge) penalty/cost of spawning shell processes, sure.

Answer (score 0):

`perl -lanE'$h{$F[0]} .= " $F[1]" END{say $_.$h{$_} foreach keys %h}' *.txt`

Should work, can't test it as I'm answering from my mobile. You also could sort the output if you put a `sort` between `foreach` and `keys`.

Answer (score 0):

```
pr -m -t -s\  file1.txt file2.txt|gawk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4}'> finalfile.txt
```

Considering file1 and file2 have 2 columns and 1 and 2 represents columns from file1 and 3 and 4 represents columns from file2.

You can also print any column from each file in this way and it will take any number of files as input. If your file1 has 5 columns for example, then $6 will be the first column of the file2.